# 404 Error in flask webapp unable to find reason

Tags: python, html, flask

When running the webapp a 404 error appears, the error doesnt even allow my error html to run even when changing it to the most basic of templates. I dont know where my request is being not found.

Ive tried removing all of the style sheets from base.html to see if its those, I tried changing the error.html to see if it will actually run I've attempted to comment out all url_for's in the html files.

I commented out the results bit so i dont think its that.

routes.py

```
    from app import app
    from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
    from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException
    from app.results import clean_data, get_response


    @app.errorhandler(Exception)
    def handle_error(e):
        '''
        code = 500
        if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
            code = e.code'''
        print(str(e))
        return render_template("error.html")


    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        data = clean_data(request.form)
        response = get_response(data)
        print(response)
        return render_template("index.html")
```

base.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">


            <title>Default Scorer -- Ebury</title>
            <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width", initial-scale = 1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
            <!-- CSS-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <!-- JS-->
            <!-- [if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif] -->
            <script src="https://ebury-chameleon.s3.amazonaws.com/1.17.0/scripts/ebury-chameleon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        </head>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/Ebury.png') }}"  width="80" height="30" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="/"><b>Default Scorer</b> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/logout">Log out</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav>

        <body>
        </body>

</html>
```

index.html(only relevant parts its got a lot of forms)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

            <div class="m-1 pb-3"></div>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 push-md-3">
                        <div class = "m-0 pb-0">
                            <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class = "form-group">
                                        <div class = "row">
                                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <span class = "input-group-text">BVD ID Number</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "bvd_id_number" name = "bvd_id_number">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </form>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block scripts %}

    <script>
        (function() {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    }, false);
                });
            }, false);
        })();
    </script>

    {% endblock %}
```

error.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>ERROR</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ERROR</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So what happens is that the form doesnt appear and it seems only base.html appears with nothing else, the icon doesnt appear either but I tried commenting that out and that doesnt work.

The error printed is "404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. IF you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again"

Comment: This is probably a different issue, but does index.html extend base.html? I don't see a {%block content%} in base.html anyway.

Comment: Yes it does, sorry that i didn't include that in the code i think i just copy pasted from a bt low

Comment: This looks like a routing issue. Since your error handler isn't being called, either, try to verify that you are actually working with the correct file. It seems like this routing file isn't loaded.

Comment: What do you mean?
Im running the correct file as when i change something that change occurs. It was running before and I don't think I've changed anything

Comment: I just meant that I've managed to troubleshoot the wrong file in the past.

Comment: Oh lol, im pretty sure thats not happening here.

Answer (score 0):

To future people: I solved because the base.html did not specify where it had to be extended. The correct base.html code would be:

````
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">


            <title>Default Scorer -- Ebury</title>
            <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width", initial-scale = 1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
            <!-- CSS-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <!-- JS-->
            <!-- [if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif] -->
            <script src="https://ebury-chameleon.s3.amazonaws.com/1.17.0/scripts/ebury-chameleon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        </head>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/Ebury.png') }}"  width="80" height="30" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="/"><b>Default Scorer</b> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/logout">Log out</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav>

        <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        </body>
{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}
</html>```
````